# How to recognize a button press for programmatic UIButton Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

Im using this code to create UIBarButtons programmatically on my Navigation Bar, how can I set the Buttons to send IBActions programmatically. I.O.W. how can I programmatically place a view to recognize the UITapGestureRecognizer(set the touchUpInside event) and connect it to an IBAction?

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:153/256.0 green:204/256.0 blue:51/256.0 alpha:1.0];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];

self.navigationItem.title = @"Feed";

UIBarButtonItem *cameraItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *postItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myIcon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *addPlusItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *optionsItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myIcon2.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];

NSArray *cameraAndPostItem = @[cameraItem, postItem];
NSArray *addPlusAndOptionsItem = @[optionsItem, addPlusItem];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = cameraAndPostItem;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = addPlusAndOptionsItem;
```

**EDIT:** I am trying to perform a segue when the user presses the UIBarButtonItem, which I have implemented programmatically.

Comment: You're going to need to re-clarify. I have no idea what you're trying to do. You want one button to "press" another?

Comment: I took @Daij Djan's advice and set the action to a selector method call, but now I want to perform a segue inside this method, how do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the target and the action of the buttons

```
UIBarButtonItem *cameraItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:nil];
cameraItem.target = self;
cameraItem.action = @selector(cameraItemButtonInvoked);

//or short
UIBarButtonItem *cameraItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:@selector(cameraItemButtonInvoked)];
```

...

```
- (IBAction)cameraItemButtonInvoked {
    .... // e.g.
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetail" sender:sender];
}
```

Comment: How do I connect the IBAction? Also Im having difficulty understanding how I can call the segue that I want to call with the IBACtion method.

Comment: it is connected to the bar button. you set its target to an instance + its action to a Selector and it is connected

Answer (score 1):

You'll be setting the action to UIBarButton like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addPlusItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addSomething:)];
```

Note the action part, there you are passing the selector to be called. Write that selector in your ViewController like this:

```
- (void) addSomething:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"I'm adding something..");
}
```

Do the same for rest of the buttons.

Comment: how can I perform a segue inside this method?

Comment: my @interface does not declare the selector? I'm getting an error message using this, Im probably forgetting to declare the selector? but I have the method declared..